# Building a Searchable Glossary webpage

Tags: javascript, search

Is there a way to build a search functionality within a single webpage? I need to convert a small glossary into a webpage and they want it to be searchable(The glossary is only about 30 words and definitions). I would like to do this with javascript, as I do not have experience with any DB type of programming, and my initial thought is to have a text input field and based on the user's input jump to a hash URL in the page (if the hash exists). Is this the best way to go about doing this? I have been doing some searching for some sort of plugin that provides this type of feature but have not come across anything? Any type of direction on the best of handling something like this would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of SEARCH I guess a better word for what I'm look for is FILTER. So a way to filter a defined list as the user is typing into a search field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that I threw together...

```
var foos = document.getElementsByClassName('foo'),
    srch = document.querySelector('#search');

srch.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    var i = 0;
    for(; i < foos.length; i++) {
        if(foos[i].innerHTML == srch.value) {
            foos[i].classList.add('match');
        } else {
            foos[i].classList.remove('match');
        }
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8ypc5/)**

You may want to wrap the matching functionality in a setTimeout or something to avoid searching on every single keypress.